# Unable to add key

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I'm pretty new the LUIS. I have made an app in LUIS but now I'm unable to add key in luis.

I double checked that I'm signed-in with the same account on both azure and luis and also using the same region i.e. westeurope

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you open F12/dev tools and try again. Save the HAR file and post the error from F12? by error, I mean one of the http calls to the backend of LUIS will return 4xx and have a message.

Answer (score 0):

Please [select the tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys) so that you can see the available keys associated with it. In the screenshot you shared, there is no tenant selected and asks to select a tenant. Selecting the tenant will resolve the issue.